# django postgres password authentication failed

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to connect Django with postgres but i am getting this error

this is my setting.py:

```
'default' : {
    'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME' : 'login',
    'USERNAME' : 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD' :'123',
    'HOST' : 'localhost',
    'PORT' : '5432'
}
```

Comment: The user name in the error message (=> "tbosss") doesn't match your settings (=> "USERNAME: 'postgres'").

Comment: that the problem its not connecting at all

Comment: try add this line in db settings 'ATOMATIC_REQUESTS':True,

Comment: I repeat: __The user name in the error message (=> "tbosss") doesn't match your settings (=> "USERNAME: 'postgres'")__. Either you're using different settings than those you posted or you're trying to manually connect to the db at some point with a different username, but in both cases no one can help you debug this kind of problem without correct informations (and even then - postgres is kind of PITA when it comes to permissions).

Comment: @c.grey this should be "ATOMIC" (not "ATOMATIC"), and it won't solve the problem anyway.

Comment: is your pc name is `tbosss`?

Comment: yep its pc name

Comment: USER, not USERNAME, at leas for django.db.backends.postgresql engine with Django 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

psql (default client for PostgreSQL) tries to connect with current OS user when no user specified and I think that psycopg2 does that too.

> The PostgreSQL documentation contains the complete list of the
>   supported parameters. Also note that the same parameters can be passed
>   to the client library using environment variables.

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS

When I check psycopg2 tutorial, I see that **USERNAME** option must be changed to **USER**.

> psycopg2.connect("dbname='template1' user='dbuser' host='localhost'
>   password='dbpass'")

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial